# how to create my queru in spring roo

Tags: spring-roo, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i am a beginner.

I am try to created a custom finder. and used  "repository jpa " command.
this is my repository:

```
    @RooJpaRepository(domainType = Speaker.class)
public interface SpeakerRepository {
    @Query("select u from Speaker u where username = :un")  
    public List<Speaker> findllAllSpeakersNamed(@Param("un") String lastname); 
    }
```

Service:

```
public class SpeakerServiceImpl implements SpeakerService {
@Autowired 
SpeakerRepository speakerRepository;
public List<Speaker> findllAllSpeakersNamed(String lastName) {
    return speakerRepository.findllAllSpeakersNamed(lastName);
 }
}
```

and controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/findASpeaker/**")
@Controller
public class FindASpeaker {

    @Autowired
    SpeakerServiceImpl speakerServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "{id}")
    public void post(@PathVariable Long id, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    }


    @RequestMapping
    public  String  index(@RequestParam("lastname")String lastname) {
        String Lastname=lastname;
        ModelMap modle=new ModelMap ();


        List<Speaker> list = speakerServiceImpl.findllAllSpeakersNamed(Lastname);
        modle.addAttribute("speakers",list);

        return  "findASpeaker/index";
    }  

}
```

This can not work.,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Your repository is an interface.  Spring Data is supposed to auto-detect the queries based on the name of the method, such that "List findUsersByNameDesc(String name);" will auto-create a method to query for all Users with the given name.  The @Query simply tells it not to  guess at the query, but use the one you provide instead.  An example can be [found here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query).